# Yearly quarters formula

Tags: google-sheets, analytics

In my Google Spreadsheet I need to display the current quarter of the year for my analytics report.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try this (add your reference cell with date or a date to the place I've pointed with **)

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(*reference or date*)/3;0)
```

Comment: It works, I used today() as reference date so it shows the current quarter.

Thanks !

Comment: Note that if the cell is blank, it will return `4` as blank/empty cell defaults to `December 30, 1899` per https://sheetshelp.com/month/

Answer (score 4):

### Tl;dr

Blank cells resolve to `-` instead of `4` :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A10),"-",CONCAT("Q", ROUNDUP(MONTH(A10)/3,0)))
```

Note: for locale using `;` as separator (E.g. France, Italy, [more details](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A10);"-";CONCAT("Q"; ROUNDUP(MONTH(A10)/3;0)))
```

### Detailed answer

Building on [Han Soalone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454860/han-soalone)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30619818/311288): if the cell is blank, it will return `4` as a blank (= empty) cell defaults to `December 30, 1899` ([source](https://sheetshelp.com/month))

I suggest using `ISBLANK` to test first if the cell is empty, then `CONCAT` the letter `Q` to the quarter number to obtain:

- Q1,
- Q2,
- Q3,
- Q4,
- `-` for empty cells

Formula based on date in cell `A10`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A10),"-",CONCAT("Q", ROUNDUP(MONTH(A10)/3,0)))
```